# How to collapse and expand a ListItem.Standard?

Tags: application-development, qml, ubuntu-sdk

For the app I am developing I would like to have a list with sections that I can collapse or expand. The item in the sections can be clicked and open a DefaultSheet.

So, for example in the "Ubuntu UI toolkit Gallery" in the List Items tab, in "GroupedList", I would like to be able to click on "fruit" and collapse the list, and click again on it and expand the list.

How can I do that? Is that possible? (It is for ListItem.ValueSelector so it might be possible)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "retract" and "develop". Could you clarify?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry I am French, so I don't know the perfect word, is "Collapsible" ok? I mean that I have something like a ValueSelector but no selection in the header. Just when I click the List, it shows all the possibility and then I click one possibility and I get a popover. (the part with the popover is easy, it is the rest whisi isn't)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: If there is no way to do it I can make a bug report. But where? for what paquage?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is the **ListItem.Expandable** SDK component. It was added in the 14.10 SDK Framework which is at the time of writing this answer is a development framework. It provides the capability to collapse and expand the listitem on clicking it.

I would recommend you read the API documentation [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/qml/sdk-14.10/Ubuntu.Components.ListItems.Expandable/) to learn more about the component and see how to use it in your application.

#### Code Sample

Here is a small code sample that creates such a component,

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import Ubuntu.Components 1.1
import Ubuntu.Components.ListItems 1.0 as ListItem

MainView {
    id: mainView

    width: units.gu(50)
    height: units.gu(75)

    Page {
        title: "Sample Expandable App"

        Column {
            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
            clip: true

            Repeater {
                model: 2
                ListItem.Expandable {
                    id: expandingItem1
                    expandedHeight: contentCol1.height + units.gu(1)

                    onClicked: {
                        expanded = !expanded;
                    }

                    Column {
                        id: contentCol1
                        anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
                        Item {
                            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right}
                            height: expandingItem1.collapsedHeight
                            Label {
                                anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right; verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter}
                                text: "Item " + index
                            }
                        }

                        UbuntuShape {
                            anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
                            height: index % 2 == 0 ? units.gu(6) : units.gu(18)
                            color: "khaki"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Clock App Giff

I have attached a gif below where we use in the clock app to set the alarm duration.

[image]